# How Do I Connect to an older (downgraded) database (.mdf file) from SQL Server 2008 R2 in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

I am making a simple WinForms application for a client. The application's database does not run on their PC because they get the message

> ...MDF file cannot be opened because it is version 904. The server supports version 852 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.

The user cannot upgrade the SQL Server of their PC, so I have resorted to downgrading the database. I generated the scripts of the old database, connected to a SQL Server 2008 R8 instance in SQL Server Management Studio, and recreated the database but in 2008 R2 version. Now I am trying to add the database as a datasource to my project, but I get the following error:

[image]

I am aware that by right clicking on the `.mdf` file in server explorer and modifying the connection then pressing OK will upgrade the database. But I don't want to upgrade the database. I just want to connect to it.

When I modify the connection string with the `.mdf` file itself to become like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myDB" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\NewConstruction.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\medaw\source\repos\Construction\Construction\bin\Release\NewConstruction.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.'

Comment: you need also the old system try it with windows 7 and vs 2017

Comment: Is there another way? I can't just try it with Windows 7 and VS 2017. My internet is slow and I don't have enough time to install them.

Comment: the sql server doesn't run under windows 10 or 11, see if someone around you has a licence and key and cd around, but you don't need it https://learningsqlserver.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/how-can-i-open-mdf-and-ldf-files-in-sql-server-attach-tutorial-troublshooting/  install the mdf, and use only basic sql commands, nothing new and fancy like string_split or so, you need to check if you use a function since when it is supported, the Framework for your program choose Dot net 2 and every thing will be al right

Comment: Well then, I've done some research and version 852 is SqlServer 2016. If I change it from 2008 to 2016, will I need to download VS2017 or Windows 7?

Comment: like you see here https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/releases/2022/compatibility you can develop for windws 7 and sql server 2008 r2 with vs 2022, but if you have something other than windows 7 you need a operating system that fits. The basic problem is the dotn et frame work, net 7 isn't supported for example in windiows 7, so you need to check which your client supports, as the system gets older and older you need oder and older  visual studios that is why i have vms with vs 2005 vs 2010 and vs 2017, all versions run under windows 10, so see what your client supprts , install vs